# Unable to run build for gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Gitlab unable to complete gitlab-ci build for the project. Logs showing it cannot connect to docker endpoint.

> gitlab-ci-multi-runner 0.7.1 (ee7a001) Using Docker executor with
>   image ruby:2.1 ... Pulling docker image mysql:latest ...
>
> ERROR: Build failed with: cannot connect to Docker endpoint

Please provide some solution.

Comment: Do you have Docker Engine installed on the node with the CI runner?

Comment: Yes, it is installed.

Comment: Is the user you run gitlab-ci with part of docker group ? Else you have to :  groupadd docker service docker restart usermod -a -G docker user1

Answer (score 0):

Update your runner and docker daemon, since meanwhile the dockerHub registry endpoint has been changed with the docker V2 api.

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot connect to Docker endpoint` suggests it's a network issue. Double check that the host your runner is on can access docker. According to wireshark, when I run a `docker pull` I'm hitting registry-1.docker.io, but that might not be the same for you or on the runner. If you can find what it is, make sure your runner can access it with nc, curl, etc. If not, you'll have to check your ACL's or security groups.